# Flag Ids that satisfy conditions, but Ids are not unique per row

Tags: powerbi, dax

My dataset looks like this (sorry for the terrible drawing) [image: Dataset]

I have non unique ids in each row and a coupon each time.

What I want to do is count how many Ids there are that have both coupon "a" and coupon "b".

For example in the picture only id 1 is to be counted.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Please test this measure, and let me know If It solves your problem:

```
CountUnique =
VAR TblSummary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( YourTable[ID] ),
        "UniqueCount", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ), YourTable[COUPON] IN { "a", "b" } )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTX ( FILTER ( TblSummary, [UniqueCount] > 1 ), [UniqueCount] )
```

If we test it on a table visual :

[image: GGGGGGGGG]

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you!

Comment: Hi @KostasBitos Pleased to hear that It works. You're welcome. 

Answer (score 1):

similar approach with Ozan Sen

Modelling --> New Table

```
Count Table =
VAR _slt =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID] ),
        "Count",
            CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'Table'[ID] ), 'Table'[Coupon] IN { "a", "b" } ) / 2
    )
RETURN
    FILTER ( _slt, [Count] >= 1 )
```

or as a measure

```
A or B Count =
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( 'Table'[ID] ),
        CONTAINSROW ( { "A", "B" }, 'Table'[Coupon] )
    ) > 1,
    1,
    0
)
```

Comment: Checked this measure and it works too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

another customizable table :

```
Another Table =
VAR _search =
    DATATABLE ( "Search", STRING, { { "a" }, { "b" } } )
VAR _counted =
    COUNTROWS ( _search )
VAR _slt =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID] ),
        "Count",
            CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'Table'[ID] ), 'Table'[Coupon] IN _search ) / _counted
    )
RETURN
    FILTER ( _slt, [Count] >= 1 )
```

or more customizable measure :

```
A or B Count =
VAR _search =
    DATATABLE ( "Search", STRING, { { "a" }, { "b" } } )
 VAR _counted =
    COUNTROWS ( _search )
RETURN
    IF (
        CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'Table'[ID] ), CONTAINSROW ( _search, 'Table'[Coupon] ) ) >= _counted,
        1,
        0
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Checked the measure and it does work, how would go about turning this into a calculated column if needed?

Comment: @KostasBitos i would not prefer calculated column actually but let me try...

Comment: @KostasBitos in this option, you can customize easily as per your real table and columns...